# Following a Twilio Tutorial to Record Phone Calls: Resulting in a 404 HTTP Error

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, record, twilio-api

I'm following this tutorial linked [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-record-phone-calls-node-js) which incorporates Twilio Programmable Voices and Express to record inbound phone calls. I followed the tutorial exactly, set up a ngrok public server, connected it to my http://localhost:3000, and I get the following output when I navigate to my ngrok link:

Cannot GET /

When I check ngrok in my terminal, it says "404 Not Found" for a GET (which is not in my code) and POST request. If I add a simple GET request to my code (such as "Hello World"), then in the browser, I see "Hello World" when I run my application. In the terminal, GET is able to succeed but POST still returns a "404 Not Found".

I've checked several other stack overflow questions, I've tried importing body-parser as recommended and adding these two lines:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

For reference, my directory has a record.js file, package.json and package-lock.json files, and necessary node modules. In my Twilio Console, I did set up a web hook for my Twilio # to the ngrok link which looks like this: http://39b62a0c34b1.ngrok.io. To show my order of executions:

1. Run `./ngrok http 3000` in Mac Terminal
2. Run `node record.js` in VS Code terminal
3. Navigate to http://39b62a0c34b1.ngrok.io
4. Call my Twilio #

The voice message tells me that there's a problem with my application. I've checked the Twilio Debugger and I receive back a 11200 Error informing me that my ngrok link returned a "HTTP status code of 404".

**I'm quite new to Node.js, Express, and Twilio, so any and all help is appreciated (please simplify your explanation)!** I want to be a Developer Evangelist for Twilio someday so I'm more than prepared to make mistakes now to troubleshoot them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`, not JSON, for Webhhooks.

You will need to add Express middleware to parse `urlencoded` data out.

The 3rd Line:

```
// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

[Where do I find the specifications for inbound HTTP requests to my server?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq#where-do-i-find-the-specifications-for-inbound-http-requests-to-my-server)

Let me know how it goes.

Still not clear why you are getting a 404 - Not Found. The app.post should kick in for POST operations. `app.all` for all operations. Are you using the /record path in your testing?